# Remove Extension From URL

Tags: .htaccess

localhost/PHPExcel/Documentation/Examples/Reader/exampleReader01.php

I am Trying To remove extension but this is not working for above URL

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$/Examples/Reader/ $1.php
```

Can Anyone Help Me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Hey Thanx For Reply. But This Is only Removing the extension it is not displaying the page it gives 404 ERROR

Comment: My .htaccess is located in Documentation Folder.

Comment: No idea what is documentation folder? Find out what is your document root? What is exact URL you are entering in browser?